# "Preencher" linhas vazias de uma coluna do data frame, com base no valor da primeira linha dessa coluna. (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Bom dia! estou com um problema e gostaria de pedir ajuda de vocês.

Estou com centenas de tabelas de dados climáticos para compilar, já automatizei muita coisa no libreoffice para facilitar o trabalho no R.

O que eu quero é saber como "ensinar" o data frame a preencher as linhas vazias com o valor da *primeira* linha da coluna.

Segue exemplo que montei (corrigi o exemplo com auxílio do Rui Barradas):

```
MES <- c("JANEIRO", "FEVEREIRO", "MARÇO")  
CHUVA <- c(220, 330, 400)  
ESTACAO <- c("A401", "" ,"" )

SALVADOR_A401 <- data.frame(MES, CHUVA, ESTACAO)
```

Dessa forma, a coluna `ESTACAO`, deveria preencher todas as linhas vazias com base na variável `"A401"`.

OBSERVAÇÃO: Eu sei fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
SALVADOR_A401 %>% mutate(ESTACAO = "A401")
```

Mas esse tipo de solução é manual, queria uma solução no qual eu não precisasse declarar o valor da primeira linha. Pois teria que preencher umas 5.000 planilhas dessa forma.

Comment: A base não será antes `SALVADOR_A401 <- data.frame(MES, CHUVA, ESTACAO)`?

Comment: É isso mesmo, esse A, B e C no exemplo foi desatenção minha, sua observação está correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o mesmo dataset criado na resposta do Rui Barradas:

```
MES <- c("JANEIRO", "FEVEREIRO", "MARÇO")  
CHUVA <- c(220, 330, 400)  
ESTACAO <- c("A401", "" ,"" )

SALVADOR_A401 <- data.frame(MES, CHUVA, ESTACAO)
```

Com `mutate()` cria-se a coluna `ESTACAO2`. Em seguida, com `case_when()` define-se a seguinte condição: nas situações em que `ESTACAO` for diferente de `""`, deve-se preencher a coluna `ESTACAO2` com o conteúdo da coluna `ESTACAO`.
Por padrão, o que não se encaixa na regra, a própria função `case_when()` transforma em `NA`.

```
SALVADOR_A401 %>% 
  mutate(ESTACAO2 = case_when(ESTACAO != "" ~ ESTACAO))

        MES CHUVA ESTACAO ESTACAO2
1   JANEIRO   220    A401     A401
2 FEVEREIRO   330             <NA>
3     MARÇO   400             <NA>
```

A partir daí pode-se usar a função `fill()` para completar os valores das demais linhas.

```
SALVADOR_A401 %>% 
  mutate(ESTACAO2 = case_when(ESTACAO != "" ~ ESTACAO)) %>% 
  fill(ESTACAO2)


        MES CHUVA ESTACAO ESTACAO2
1   JANEIRO   220    A401     A401
2 FEVEREIRO   330             A401
3     MARÇO   400             A401
```

Se não quiser criar a segunda coluna de `ESTACAO2`, basta aplicar o mutate à própria coluna `ESTACAO`

```
SALVADOR_A401 %>% 
  mutate(ESTACAO = case_when(ESTACAO != "" ~ ESTACAO)) %>% 
  fill(ESTACAO)

        MES CHUVA ESTACAO
1   JANEIRO   220    A401
2 FEVEREIRO   330    A401
3     MARÇO   400    A401
```

Comment: Boa noite, muito obrigado pela solução. Confesso que tenho mais intimidade com o tidyverse, e esse caminho também ajudou muito. Entendi melhor. Gratidão!!

Answer (score 2):

Se as colunas da base forem os vetores da pergunta e não de uns vetores `A`, `B` e `C`, então tente o seguinte. Além do pacote `dplyr` também é usada uma função do pacote `zoo`, que não pertence ao `tidyverse`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

MES <- c("JANEIRO", "FEVEREIRO", "MARÇO")  
CHUVA <- c(220, 330, 400)  
ESTACAO <- c("A401", "" ,"" )

SALVADOR_A401 <- data.frame(MES, CHUVA, ESTACAO)

SALVADOR_A401 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(nzchar(.x), .x, NA)),
         across(everything(), ~zoo::na.locf(.x)))
#>         MES CHUVA ESTACAO
#> 1   JANEIRO   220    A401
#> 2 FEVEREIRO   330    A401
#> 3     MARÇO   400    A401
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado, a situação foi resolvida com seu código.            
  Realmente o correto foi a forma como tu exemplificou o data frame, coloquei esse A, B e C por desatenção ao escrever o exemplo.